# Javascript popup window focus

Tags: javascript, popup, focus

Is there a way to bring a javascript pop-up to the front of all applications if the browser from where the pop-up is generated is minimalized? 
Tried:

```
newwindow=window.open('sessionExpiresSoon.html','SessionExpires','height=200,width=150');

newwindow.focus();
```

But this only focuses if the browser is opened or browsing in other tabs and so on.

Comment: No, there isn't. If there would have been a way, you probably have saw  ads popup even when your browser is minimized :)

Comment: If you ever figure out a way to do this, *don't do it anyway*.  Focus-stealing popups are pure evil.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

new tab (no mater if it's pop-up) is a part of browser.
if your programm (named browser) is inactive in your operating system, you can make it blinking as max.